# How to handle IIS recycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, iis-10

I found that my **ASP.NET application** running under **IIS**, is completely restarting time to time. Is it important to let the application pool **recycle**?

What is exactly happening when the application pool is recycling?

Is it guaranteed that **Application Start event** will be invoked, so I can restart my "timed jobs"?

Is it possible that the recycling is killing a current request or flow and ruining user experience? If yes, how to handle that?

I am using **IIS 10**, and the default recycling is set to Regular Time Interval 1740 minutes (29 hrs).

Thanks!

Comment: seem like questions that could be answered with a little research.

Comment: I was hoping someone had earlier experience with this and has some advice.

Comment: like I said, a quick search would answer.

Comment: There are known issues with certain versions of IIS. I would start with determining which version you're running.

Comment: IIS 10, and default recycling is set to 1740 minutes (Regular time interval) (29 Hrs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it important to let the application pool recycle?

Yes - mostly to clean up any leaked memory or other resources, but there are other benefits as well.

> Is it guaranteed that Application Start event will be invoked, so I can restart my "timed jobs"?

No - `Application Start` occurs when a *request* is made.

IIS is not the right platform to invoke scheduled jobs.  Use a Windows Service or the Task Scheduler instead.

> Is it possible that the recycling is killing a current request or flow and ruining user experience? If yes, how to handle that?

If you rely heavily on a memory-based session, then yes, it's possible.  Existing requests will be given a reasonable chance to complete, so if there are long-running requests then they may be killed.  The session will definitely be cleared if you are using an in-memory session.  The best way to get around that is to change to a more persistent session like a database-persisted session.

Bottom line - if scheduled tasks are your main concern then use a different platform than IIS.  IIS is designed as a request/response platform.

Comment: Thank you @DStanley. Very helpful.